# Getting Error: Unknown authenticationOk message typeMessage { name: 'authenticationOk', length: 23 }

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli, postgresql-13

I have installed Postgres 13 in windows 10.
Configured all the right credentials in the environment file of the project.
The project uses the below dependencies and it was created in ubuntu.

```
"pg": "^7.4.3",
"pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
"sequelize": "4.38.0",
"sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0"
```

I'm trying to set it up in windows.
And getting the below error in windows 10.

```
Error: Unknown authenticationOk message typeMessage { name: 'authenticationOk', length: 23 }
```

When I hit
`npx sequelize db:migrate`
in the terminal for migrating the tables in the database.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I was able to fix this by upgrading `pg` from `"^7.4.3"` to `"^8.7.1"`.

Comment: Yes, the same solution worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me as well. The situation was different but the error was the same.

Comment: worked for me, absolute gem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment by @nanaya [here](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1508#issuecomment-445474535)

You can try to use `pg-native`, and set env to `NODE_PG_FORCE_NATIVE=1` before executing the migration.

```
$ npm i pg-native
$ export NODE_PG_FORCE_NATIVE=1
$ npx sequelize db:migrate
```

Answer (score -1):

This issue comes if your Database Host is incorrect. In my case I'm using Docker and change DB host in consule file from localhost to your DB server.